# React native build.gradle showing could not find method signincongfigs for argument

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

Hello I am new to react and was working to build to my application which can run on any application so applied some method but in build.gradle it showing - Could not find method signingConfigs() for arguments [build_2a4ceg7syu83544h419wbwh8m$_run_closure1@17221d88] on root project 'test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

my build.gradle file is

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and my gradle.properties is

```
 android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true

# Version of flipper SDK to use with React Native
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.33.1

MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=123456
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=123456
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it in your `android/app/build.gradle` file.

Here,

```
android{
....

// add here
}
```

Comment: how to do that , please explain

Comment: it is showing > Could not find method android() for arguments [build_2a4ceg7syu83544h419wbwh8m$_run_closure1@60e7ebce] on root project 'test' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

change

```js
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

to this >>

```js
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```